# How to handle config files and default settings when using Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, config

I was wondering what the best practices were for handling configuration files for your scripts when using Composer.

To elaborate, if I have a script that has several options or settings I'd usually just add them as variables or constants in a `config.php` file or something similar, and then require the file my script. Or, if the script is a simple class then just use class properties... basic stuff, right?

So, my question is, with the advent of PSR-4, autoloading, Composer, etc., what is the preferred way of doing this?

It feels wrong to ask users to directly edit the file(s) in vendor/ (eg: to edit a config file or properties in a class, etc.). Plus, wouldn't those edits get overwritten on updates?

I thought about using `defined()` in my script to look for certain constants, which the user could set in their own config files. This would probably work fine for smaller projects, but might become cumbersome and hard to scale. For some scripts it might also be difficult to come up with sane defaults in the event that the constants aren't defined by the user.

I also thought about using one of Composer's "hooks" to trigger a script that moves a config file somewhere like the project's root directory. But then I hate to just drop a random config file in the user's project...

Am I overthinking this? How do you guys typically handle this situation?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: As the post says, I'm wondering what the best practices are for dealing with external configuration files when using autoloading, such as with Composer.

Comment: Usually it's bound to the framework by configuration and has a Configuration class.

Comment: In cases where a framework is used that makes sense. But I was asking more about smaller scripts, or when frameworks aren't being used.

Comment: I used incorrect word. I'd use some DependencyInjection component (usually 1-2 packages, not the whole framework), that handles this configuration loading. Something like this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a configuration file. Let the code which includes your project set configuration values at run time.

If you are working in object oriented php you may want to take any required configuration parameters as arguments to your constructor or factory method, and provide setter methods for optional parameters, or parameters for which a sensible default value exists.